# How to change color of aui:button

Tags: javascript, liferay-aui

I have a button with aui:

```
<aui:button type="submit" value="Update Time"
cssClass="updatebutton"></aui:button>
```

I set css class:

```
.updatebutton {
    color: black;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
}
```

But it not effect. How can I change color of aui-button

Comment: What does the aui:button render like after the page is loaded? You should target this in your css instead.